# Hyperlinks to headings with line breaks

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, line-breaking

I have a document with some long heading titles. I use `\\` to create line breaks in these headings to have them fit my two column TOC as I please. The problem is that, when I use `hyperref`, within the document's text, to create links to those headings with long titles, I end up with links with line-breaks.

How do I create hyperlinks to headings with line-breaks without having those hyperlinks appear with the same line-breaks?

Thank you.

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[expand]{gettitlestring}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % For links' color
\usepackage{colortbl} % To define colors
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{caption} % To change the way captions are labelled
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage[rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller and quotes small
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For Numero symbol
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone


\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{bookmark}
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{\def\\{}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\part{Fish}

\chapter{Lyrics}

\chapter{Lyrics}
\section[Fortification and \texorpdfstring{\\}{}Exaltation and Mumification]{Fortification and Exaltation and Mumification}\label{sec:Mumification}
\section[Germination and Photography and Extraction]{Germination, Photography, and \texorpdfstring{\\}{}Extraction}\label{sec:Germination}

This is a sentence (see \nameref{sec:Mumification}) linking to a heading with a line-break in it.

This is another sentence (see \nameref{sec:Germination}) linking to a heading without line-break in it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use \texorpdfstring{\\}{} to hide the linebreak.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me a working example? I'm having trouble with the syntax: `\section{\texorpdfstring{Fortification and\\Exaltation and Mumification}{Fortification and Exaltation and Mumification}}\label{sec:Mumification}`

Comment: I will do it in the next half hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment was wrong, \texorpdfstring is not relevant here (beside helping to avoid a warning). The title is passed for the `\nameref` through `\GetTitleString` and so you will have to add the line break to the list of commands to disable. Be aware that this means that the title has to be expanded and that fragile material might break.

```
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[expand]{gettitlestring} % use expand method
\usepackage{titlesec,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\ttl@straight@i
 {\def\@currentlabelname{#2}}
 {\GetTitleString{#2}\let\@currentlabelname\GetTitleStringResult}
 {}
 {\fail}
 \makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{bookmark}
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{\def\\{}}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\part{Fish}

\chapter{Lyrics}
\section[Fortification and \texorpdfstring{\\}{}Exaltation and Mumification]{Fortification and Exaltation and Mumification}\label{sec:Mumification}
\section[Germination and Photography and Extraction]{Germination, Photography, and \texorpdfstring{\\}{}Extraction}\label{sec:Germination}

This is a sentence (see \nameref{sec:Mumification}) linking to a heading with a line-break in it.

This is another sentence (see \nameref{sec:Germination}) linking to a heading without line-break in it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I inserted your code in mine (see my edited code above) and I fail to get your result. Could it be that some other package is interfering with `\GetTitleString`?

Comment: Easy to find out: If my document works and yours fail you only need to add the packages one after the other to find the culprit. (it is titlesec, I would avoid it, it redefines everything and is difficult to debug).

Comment: Well, then, I'll have to live with that minor heading/linking issue, 'cause I'm not about to try and make an alternative to `titlesec` work. Thank you.

Comment: I added a patch for titlesec. It assumes that gettitlestring is loaded.

Comment: It works. Thank for your generous time on this. Virtual beers are on me.